# Strange error while sending SMS

Tags: android

I am trying to send SMS with Java Code. It works fine when I send an English SMS. But fails when I try with the Russian message given below. It throws `NullPointerException`.

```
String message = "Здравствуйтe, сейчас я не могу ответить на Ваш звонок.  Перезвоните через 10 минут, если Вам не ответили. Спасибо";  
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,  
    new Intent(this, RussianSmsProblemActivity.class), 0);                  
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();  

sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, message,sentPI,deliveredPI);//getting Null Pointer Exception here
```

**There is no problem with the code, the NullpointerException comes in the Android API. Request some expert to please guide on this problem.**

here is the exception stack trace...

```
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): java.lang.NullPointerException  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:79)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.test.RussianSmsProblemActivity.sendSms(RussianSmsProblemActivity.java:102)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.test.RussianSmsProblemActivity$1.onClick(RussianSmsProblemActivity.java:39)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)  
  12-15 16:48:32.994: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you should put the Logcat output also.

Comment: I'd be curious to know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is happening because Russian character consume `2` bytes in UTF-8. So the message is exceeding the `160` byte limit. Try using `sendMultiPartMessage()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to encode the `String message` in different ways before handing it off to the SmsManager?

Comment: Can you please suggest what do you mean by encoding the String?

Comment: I meant to explicitly state the encoding type: `message = new String("Здравствуйтe, сейчас я не могу ответить на Ваш звонок.  Перезвоните через 10 минут, если Вам не ответили. Спасибо".getBytes(), "UTF-8");` But you seem to have stumbled upon a bug which has since been fixed: Try running your code with `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />` and your message will be sent without problems